# SQL Select then Delete

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to clean out some old data from my database tables. Below shows two tables, **app_status** and **app_personal_details**.

[image]

I have the following query to select all the records (applications) from the **app_status** table which have been created over 12 months from todays date

```
select status_id  
from dbo.app_status  
where submission_date <= dateadd(month, -12, getdate()) order by 1
```

I then want to delete all the records from the **app_personal_details** table where the application_id exists in the list of retrieved status_id above.

I hope this makes sense. I would like to know a quick way of deleting the data from both tables.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
delete from app_personal_details
where application_id in (
    select status_id   
    from dbo.app_status   
    where submission_date <= dateadd(month, -12, getdate())
)
```

Comment: What if database is quickly changing on runtime and I want to select some data, save them to arraylist in java but right after that delete the same items from DB?

Comment: I mean, do I have to do 2 queries and delete based on ID? Ir is there any select+delete way?

Comment: @Ondrej I would use Laurence's approach, http://stackoverflow.com/a/13013207/39430

Answer (score 2):

You can use a subselect.

```
DELETE FROM app_personal_details
WHERE application_id IN
(
    SELECT status_id  
    FROM dbo.app_status  
    WHERE submission_date <= DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE())
)
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it and get a consistent delete over both tables is like so:

```
Select status_id  
Into #to_delete
From dbo.app_status  
Where submission_date <= dateadd(month, -12, getdate())

Create Unique Clustered Index PK_X On #to_delete (status_id)

Delete 
  app_personal_details
From
  app_personal_details apd Inner Join
  #to_delete d On apd.application_id = d.status_id

Delete 
  app_status
From 
  app_status a Inner Join
  #to_delete d On a.status_id = d.status_id
```

You may be able to do it in less statements using an output clause, or if you have a delete cascade between the two tables.

Comment: Would this allow you to output the data as well? Having that information when deleting could be super helpful for those who aren't as comfortable running SQL scripts

Answer (score 0):

If tables are big, you would prefer to delete in batches so your transaction log does not grow exponentially, and sql server will handle it faster.

You can either limit rows to delete by DELETE TOP (N) ... or by deleting specific date ranges.